Enabling Unity Catalog for Job Clusters in Azure Data Factory
I am trying to run a data engineering job on a job cluster via a pipeline in Azure Data Factory. It simply runs some code in a notebook.
I am running into the following error:
org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogNotFoundException: Catalog 'my-catalog' plugin class not found: spark.sql.catalog.my-catalog is not defined

This error occurs on this line in my code:
_get_spark().sql(f"USE CATALOG `{self.catalog}`")

My evaluation of this is that the job cluster that is being spun up does not have Unity Catalog enabled.
I can see this when I scroll down to the tags section of my cluster (the Unity Catalog tag is missing):

How can I fix this?
I figured that all I had to was set the 'Unity Catalog Access Mode' under 'Additional cluster settings' to 'Shared' when setting up my Linked Service?

What am I missing here?

Ensure the user or service principal running the pipeline has the necessary permissions to access Unity Catalog resources:


CatalogNotFoundException in Apache Spark.

This error occurs when Spark cannot find the specified catalog.
You can use the spark object directly instead of _get_spark().
I have tried below to list available catalogs:
available_catalogs = spark.catalog.listCatalogs()
for catalog in available_catalogs:
    print(catalog)

Results:
CatalogMetadata(name='adbrx02', description=None)
CatalogMetadata(name='hive_metastore', description=None)
CatalogMetadata(name='samples', description=None)
CatalogMetadata(name='system', description=None)

As you mentioned that error occurs at _get_spark().sql(f"USE CATALOG {self.catalog}")
You can try the below:
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.adbrx02", "com.databricks.spark.catalog")
spark.sql("USE CATALOG adbrx02")

In the above setting the catalog configuration & using the catalog in your SQL queries.

Hello,
No, I don't think this is the right solution for this problem. My catalog exists and this code works in an Unity Catalog enabled interactive cluster.

Can you check if your service principal & Azure databricks application have the required permissions
